# Changing Templavoila field names

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila

In the process of cleaning up some Templavoila Plus FCE, **I created a new FCE template that will replace several others**. To do so, I created some new field names to replace the old ones. *(I noticed you can't change the name of a field after creating it).*

For example, I had `field_title_A` for FCE A, `field_title_B` for FCE B, etc… Now I just have `field_title` in my new FCE template.

The problem is that if I change the FCE / Template Object for an existing content, the title field is now empty. It doesn't understand that `field_title_A` is now `field_title`.

I seriously doubt that there is a solution, but I still hope there is one.

Is there something I can do to tell TV to move the content of `field_title_A` to `field_title` or to tell it `field_title_A` is now `field_title`? Is there another way to achieve that?

---

*If I'm not using some terms properly, please, feel free to edit.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there is no such support present yet. You could open a feature request for that, but I don't think I could work out a sollution in the next 2 years.

Comment: I assume there is not much I can do then... Can you think of some way to workaround this that would save time? Or is it just a bad idea to clean up?

Comment: You can develop such a functionality for TV+ :-) And I do not know any workaround, maybe ask in the slack channel if someone else did such things already.